# Is there a problem that cannot be represented using graph?

Tags: computability, graphs, computation-models

It is obvious that the representational power of graphs are huge.
Is there a problem that cannot be represented using graph?

I have recently asked this question to my students and no answers came up. I could not answer this either.

For instance:
**Problem:** Finding the shortest path between two given cities in a country.
**Graph type:** Directed, weighted.
**Vertices:** Cities.
**Edges:** An edge $(i,j)$ indicates there is a way from city $i$ to city $j$ and weight of $(i,j)$ indicates the distance between cities $i$ and $j$.

**Problem:** Expressing your feelings using crayons.
**Graph type:** Directed, weighted.
**Vertices:** Neurons in the brain.
**Edges:** Values of electronic signals being transmitted among neurons.
**Output:** Interpretation of the signals by the brain.
(Just kidding)

**Edit:**
*Problem* in this post means, **a problem that can be solved using computers**.

Comment: Define "scenario" and "represent". With loose definitions, the representational power of a sequence of !s is just as great. If you take !!! to be a number in unary, convert in to binary and interpret as a text file.

Comment: "Express your feelings using crayons."

Comment: @Raphael please see my edit.

Comment: What about "sum of three (or more) given numbers"?

Comment: @Mowji: Addition is in P, thus reducible to all NP-complete problems, some of which are graph problems.

Comment: @Mowji Represent the natural number $i$ by any graph on $i$ vertices and sum by disjoint union.

Answer (score 4):

It's trivial to encode natural numbers as graphs (represent $n$ by a path of length $n$, or by $K_n$) so anything that can be represented as numbers can be represented as graphs.

Comment: No, that answer is too easy for me. Numbers have structure, mathematical context, they are not just counting. If you need numbers in a context a faithful representation should naturally represent that context. For example there should be a nice interpretation for "this number is prime".

Comment: @HendrikJan Peano got a long way by defining the natural numbers as the closure of $0$ under the successor operation: there's a lot you can do with "just counting". If you represent $n$ by $K_n$, then $n$ is prime iff it can't be written as a strong product except as $K_1\boxtimes K_n$.

Comment: You are right on both these counts. Still I stress the comment by Karolis above: "represent" has to be defined and chosen in a natural way to fit the context. We can represent a Turing machine program by a labelled graph easily, but that doesn't make the halting problem into a graph problem.